# Generating XML from multiple classes?

Tags: c#, .net, xml

i have another question on getting my XML serialization neat, which i can't seem to get right. my config file is as follows:

```
namespace SMCProcessMonitor
{
[Serializable()]
[XmlRoot("Email-Settings")] 
     public class Config
{     
         [XmlElement("Recipient")]
         public string recipient;
         [XmlElement("Server-port")]
         public int serverport;
         [XmlElement("Username")]
         public string username;
         [XmlElement("Password")]
         public string password;
         [XmlElement("Program")]
         public List<Programs> mPrograms = new List<Programs>();
         public string serialId;
     }

     public class Email
    {

             public string Recipient
             {
                 get
                 {
                     return SMCProcessMonitor.ConfigManager.mConfigurations.recipient;
                 }
                 set
                 {
                     SMCProcessMonitor.ConfigManager.mConfigurations.recipient = value;
                 }
             }

             public int ServerPort
             {
                 get
                 {
                     return SMCProcessMonitor.ConfigManager.mConfigurations.serverport;
                 }
                 set
                 {
                     SMCProcessMonitor.ConfigManager.mConfigurations.serverport = value;
                 }
             }
             public string Username
             {
                 get
                 {
                     return SMCProcessMonitor.ConfigManager.mConfigurations.username;
                 }
                 set
                 {
                     SMCProcessMonitor.ConfigManager.mConfigurations.username = value;
                 }
             }
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }
         [Serializable()]
    public class Programs
{
        [XmlElement("Filename")] public string mFileName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Filepath")]public string mFilePath { get; set; }
}

         public class Database
         {
             public string mSerial { get; set; }
         }
         }
```

Ideally what i want to do is have each of these three classes (email settings, database and programs) have their own tags, like so

```
<Config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"               xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<email-settings>
  <Recipient>sadh</Recipient>
  <Server-port>23</Server-port>
  <Username>lkms</Username>
  <Password>kmkdvm</Password>
</email-settings>
<Program>
  <Filename>MerlinAlarm.exe</Filename>
  <Filepath>D:\Merlin\Initsys\Merlin\Bin\MerlinAlarm.exe</Filepath>
</Program>
<database-settings>
  <serialId>1</serialId>
</database-settings>
</Config>
```

But instead i get something that resembles this:

```
 <Config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
 <Recipient>blah</Recipient>
 <Server-port>1111</Server-port>
 <Username>blah</Username>
 <Password>blah</Password>
 <Program>
 <Filename>chrome.exe</Filename>
 <Filepath>
 C:\Users\Shane\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe
 </Filepath>
 </Program>
 <serialId>1234</serialId>
 </Config>
```

Sorry to be such a bother, but this is doing my nut in now and im sure there's some fundamental logic i'm missing here..can anyone give me some pointers as to how to get this XML in the format i specified above? 
Thanks in advance, Shane.

Edit: My serialization class.

```
 namespace SMCProcessMonitor
{
public class ShanesXMLserializer
{
    private string  mFileAndPath;
    public Config   mConfigurations = null;
    public Config mConfigurationsProgram = null;



    public ShanesXMLserializer(string inFileAndPath)
    {
        mFileAndPath    = inFileAndPath;
        mConfigurations = new Config();

    }

    public bool Write()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(mConfigurations.GetType());
            StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(mFileAndPath);
            x.Serialize(writer, mConfigurations);
            writer.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception found while writing: " + ex.Message);
        };

        return false;
    }

    public bool Read()
    {
        try
        {
            XmlSerializer x = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Config));
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(mFileAndPath);
            mConfigurations = (Config)x.Deserialize(reader);
            reader.Close();
            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Exception found while reading: " + ex.Message);
        };

        return false;
    }

    public Config GetConfigEmail
    {
        get
        {
            return mConfigurations;
        }
    }


}
```

}

Edit 2:
My new config file:
@Craig - I'm using this config file, which is like you said but im still not getting the desired XML, shown after my config class.

```
           using System;
           using System.Collections.Generic;
           using System.Linq;
           using System.Xml.Serialization;
           using System.Text;
```

namespace SMCProcessMonitor
{
    [Serializable()]

```
     public class Config
{     

         public string recipient;
         public int serverport;
         public string username;
         public string password;
         public List<Programs> mPrograms = new List<Programs>();
         public string serialId;
    [XmlElement("email-settings")]
         public Email Email { get; set; }
         public Programs Programs { get; set; }
     [XmlElement("database-settings")]
         public Database Database { get; set; }


     }

     public class Email
    {
         [XmlElement("Recipient")]
         public string Recipient { get; set; }
            [XmlElement("Server-port")]
         public int ServerPort { get; set; }
         [XmlElement("Username")]
         public string Username { get; set; }
         [XmlElement("Password")]
         public string Password { get; set; }

    }
         [Serializable()]
    public class Programs
    {
        [XmlElement("Filename")] public string mFileName { get; set; }
        [XmlElement("Filepath")]public string mFilePath { get; set; }
    }

    public class Database
    {
        [XmlElement("SerialID")]
        public string mSerial { get; set; }
    }
    }
```

But i am still getting:

```
  <Config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <recipient>shane</recipient>
  <serverport>23</serverport>
  <username>oid</username>
  <password>jidj</password>
  <mPrograms/>
  </Config>
```

Comment: can you write the code section you are using for serialization?

Comment: Here is my serialization code. note that i'm running into an error now upon writing telling me that "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" since moving the variables to their respective classes.

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter using the serialization code you've added to your question, will output your desired XML using the `class` modifications I provided. To test it, you can copy the classes from my answer verbatim, populate a `Config` object and run it through the serialization code you posted. The only thing you need to change is your property getters and setters where applicable.

Comment: I think i'm derping left right and center. added the respective get/sets and still can't get it to output the way i want..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you the desired output:

```
public class Config
{
    [XmlElement("email-settings")]
    public Email Email { get; set; }

    public Program Program { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("database-settings")]
    public Database Database { get; set; }
}

public class Email
{
    public string Recipient { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("Server-port")]
    public int ServerPort { get; set; }

    public string Username { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

public class Program
{
    public string Filename { get; set; }

    public string Filepath { get; set; }
}

public class Database
{
    public string serialId { get; set; }
}
```

---

Here's a console application which will serialize an object to a file and produce the exact XML you are looking for. Just copy and paste it into a console application and take it from there.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml.Serialization;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var config = new Config
            {
                Email = new Email
                {
                    Recipient = "sadh",
                    ServerPort = 23,
                    Username = "lkms",
                    Password = "kmkdvm"
                },
                Program = new Programs
                {
                    Filename = "MerlinAlarm.exe",
                    Filepath = @"D:\Merlin\Initsys\Merlin\Bin\MerlinAlarm.exe"
                },
                Database = new Database
                {
                    serialId = "1"
                }
            };

            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Config));

            var textWriter = new StreamWriter(@"C:\config.xml");
            serializer.Serialize(textWriter, config);
            textWriter.Close();

            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    #region [Classes]

    public class Config
    {
        [XmlElement("email-settings")]
        public Email Email { get; set; }

        public Programs Program { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("database-settings")]
        public Database Database { get; set; }
    }

    public class Email
    {
        public string Recipient { get; set; }

        [XmlElement("Server-port")]
        public int ServerPort { get; set; }

        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }

    public class Programs
    {
        public string Filename { get; set; }

        public string Filepath { get; set; }
    }

    public class Database
    {
        public string serialId { get; set; }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Should I add the declarations to their respective class, or leave them in config?

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter leave them in your `Config` class. That will give you the XML in the format you mention in your question. In your question though, you have a `List<Program>` in your `Config` `class` but that is not depicted in the desired XML output you provided.

Comment: The modifications I provided in my answer will give you the XML you are looking for. For a test, why don't you comment out your classes, copy and paste the classes I provided into your app, populate a `Config` object manually for testing only and run it though your serialization code.

Comment: alright, lemme give it a go. not holding my breath though : D

Comment: Might actually quit my day job ^^ i'm using the classes exactly as you've wrote in the answer, put my few variables in there and im still getting XML as i was before. My email settings and database settings simply won't serialize in their own class tags.

Comment: this is a big ask, but is there anyway i could send you my source code and have you take a quick look at it? i'm rather stumped and am not sure what i'm doing now. Confusion has stricken.

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter I added a console application to the answer that you can copy and paste and F5 it. It will output the XML exactly like your question including the values. Of course you must change the properties to pull from your configuration afterwards.

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter I would also recommend that you follow standard naming conventions for your class and property names as well. But the first step is seeing this serialize correctly for you.

Comment: Cheers Craig. This is pretty much what i had, so i imagine the problem im having is passing data from the config form / configmanager to the config class when it gets serialized. i'll keep going ahead. also - noted about naming conventions. i'm still getting into this and every little helps. i'll keep you updated.

Comment: @Shane'Shamus'Coulter what I provided you is very different from you had and produces the XML you asked for. I recommend that you take a step back and start first by generating the XML using the console application I posted and add in your configuration helpers etc one by one. Good luck.

Comment: I've got the classes to work serializing, i'm just wondering how to get the list to serialize now without overwriting itself. any ideas?

Comment: sorted : ) thanks for all your help : D (even though i may have done it very crudely)

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to suggest a totally sideways approach here, just for simplicity's and maintenance's sake.

What if you took the source XML file and generated an XSD schema?

For instance:

```
xsd.exe MyXMLFile1.xml
```

This will generate an XML schema file (`MyXMLFile1.xsd`). Take the schema and generate classes (again using `xsd.exe`):

```
xsd.exe /c MyXMLFile1.xsd
```

This will generate a guaranteed serializable POCO that you can use going forward. The class names and properties may not match what you have in your current POCO but it **will** generate the expected XML, as well as deserialize from the XML.

The added benefit is that going forward, you will only have to modify the source XML file, then run these 2 commands to maintain the POCO.

Hope that helps...