# How to manipulate the result of a wcf soap/xml service result

Tags: c#, wcf, xml-parsing, soap-client

I used WCF to generate classes for sending a request to a soap/xml service.  I logged the outbound message and it looks right.  I used Fiddler to examine the result.

I cannot figure out how to manipulate/parse the result returned to my program.

WSDL=https://cmbhs.dshs.state.tx.us/cmbhswebservice/Service/DataDownloadService.asmx?wsdl

My code =

```
enter code here
    DataDownloadServiceSoapClient service= new DataDownloadServiceSoapClient();
    CMBHSAuthenticationHeader myheader = new CMBHSAuthenticationHeader();
    myheader.CMBHSUserName = "xxxxx";
    myheader.CMBHSPassword = "yyyyy";
    DateTime FromDate = new DateTime(2022, 10, 01);
    DateTime ToDate = new DateTime(2022, 10, 03);
    var mydata = service.Download(myheader, 449737, FromDate, ToDate, 12, 2);
```

I looked at the wcf generated classes and cannot figure out the data type of the data returned.
Suggestions?
Bob

Answer (score 0):

I found this web post.  Note there is a typo in the word "responsexml"in one space.

[Get XML of Request and Response to a web service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44767608/get-xml-of-request-and-response-to-a-web-service)

I put it and a write to file statement and got the xml data as a string:

```
            xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, myval);
            string responsexml = textWriter.ToString();
            File.WriteAllText(@"C:\work\CMBHSoutput.xml",responsexml);
```