# Generate XML with duplicate nodes from Classes in C#

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

So I reviewed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9839034/generating-xml-from-multiple-classes) post and a few others, and I'm not sure if I'm just not googling it correctly or if what I'm doing just wouldn't work, so apologises if this is a duplicate at all.

I'm creating a tool to generate some .xml files which are eventually fed into something else, I have it working but the code isn't maintainable (it's a mess) so I'm trying to re-write it using classes instead of it being hardcoded the old way.

I have this (changed the data/class names but the format is identical)

```
var sp = new Sp.Papers 
{
    Author = new Sp.Author
    {
        Name = "Steve",
        Age = 42,
        Town = "East Kilbride"
    },
    Pages = new Sp.Pages
    {
        Number = 1,
        Chapter = 1
    },
    Pages = new Sp.Pages
    {
        Number = 1,
        Chapter = 1
    }
}
```

I have another class called Sp.Pages which needs to have multiple nodes added to the xml file, but obviously the above code doesn't work as it's coming back with

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'Sp.Pages' to 'Sp.Pages[]'
```

This is what the class itself looks like

```
        private Pages[] pagesField;

            [XmlElement("Pages")]
            public InventorySoftware[] Pages
            {
                get
                {
                    return pagesField;
                }
                set
                {
                    pagesField = value;
                }
            }

        [Serializable()]
        [DesignerCategory("code")]
        [XmlType(AnonymousType = true)]
        public partial class Pages
        {
        private int numberField;

                private int chapterField;

            [XmlAttribute()]
            public int Number
            {
                get
                {
                    return numberField;
                }
                set
                {
                    numberField = value;
                }
            }

            [XmlAttribute()]
            public int Chapter
            {
                get
                {
                    return chapterField;
                }
                set
                {
                    chapterField = value;
                }
            }

    }
```

Basically, the end result needs to look like this - but I'm stumped and it's annoying me that I can't find anything on it...

```
<xml>
<author name="Steve" Age="42" Town="East Kilbride"/>
<pages number="1" chapter="1"/>
<pages number="2" chapter="1"/>
</xml>
```

Again, apologises if this is a duplicate or stupid question - I've spent a good few hours trying to find something to answer this now :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind - As I posted this, I worked out the answer.  Hate myself, if anyone else has this issue in the future (or future me when I forget), this is how you do it

```
var sp = new Sp.Papers 
{
    Author = new Sp.Author
    {
        Name = "Steve",
        Age = 42,
        Town = "East Kilbride"
    },
    Pages = new Sp.Pages[4] {
         new Sp.Pages {
            Number = 1,
            Chapter = 1
         },
         new Sp.Pages {
            Number = 2,
            Chapter = 1
         },
         new Sp.Pages {
            Number = 3,
            Chapter = 1
         },
         new Sp.Pages {
            Number = 4,
            Chapter = 1
         }
    }
}
```

Where [4] is the number of entries you'd want - so you'd obviously pull this from an integer if you didn't want it hard coded etc.

Comment: Hi, @ Laim. Does this solution solve your problem? If it is solved, you can click ‘✔’ to accept it as an answer. It is helpful for community members to solve the similar problems.